# Checking in Medical Equipment for Free

Tags: luggage, check-in, medical-devices

I’m traveling domestically to Fairbanks, AK. I travel with Lymphedema medical equipment for my disability. I know I can take this equipment on the plane for free.  Because the bag is large in size, can I check it in for free?

Comment: As a thumb rule, never put anything worth in checked luggage.  
**Especially** for medical supplies

Answer (score 2):

Whether you can check a bag for free depends entirely on your airline and the type of ticket you bought. Check your itinerary and whatever emails you got from your airline, and it should talk about checked luggage somewhere; failing that, contact the airline.

However, keep in mind that luggage gets lost very frequently. It's usually a minor inconvenience as it's generally returned to you within a day or two, but checking medical equipment is still a big risk. Unless the equipment itself is too large to fit in the overhead bin, keep it with you.

Comment: It is rather likely that there is an additional luggage allowance for medical kit.

Comment: And if it is too big for the overhead bin, you are better asking it to be treated like a stroller and checked at the door of the plane and returned to you there at the next stop or destination. Only downside is having to recheck at the gate if on a multi-leg flight.